# How can I connect an iOS app to a database?

Tags: php, ios, sqlite

I understand that there are various ways to do this. I would like to, for example, use the php language to hook up a database (such as sqlite?) to my app for something such as a login system. Is this the best way to do such a thing? If so, where can I begin in terms of introducing myself to the process? I am open to resources, code examples, etc., although a direct answer would be great.

EDIT 1: Data would be text-based. I am guessing that if there would be images, it would be a whole other ballgame?

EDIT 2: I want to clarify that coredata is locally-based, I need it connected to online database

Comment: depends on what type of storage you need to make either it coredata or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is on local then you can have [CoreData](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)  its very simple and good for new ones.

Or you can make an sqlite db and include it in your application.Or you can use plist etc.

If your application wants to interact some online database you should see how to interact with web-api. You can have online codes for databases, connection and logins but I will suggest you to do it your self and manipulate them....

In case of ambiguity feel free...

Comment: Yeah it would be an online database then.

Comment: Use json or what ever you want to have. In case of images you can have them through URL as well.

Comment: example: first you have to make a php web service that will communicate with your database what ever database is and then after you have to call and get the response of web service api to your application... have some demo over http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

To add onto James' answer, this is how I would connect to that PHP page. Note that I am using MKNetworkKit to do this.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"user":_usernameField.text,
                         @"pass":_passwordField.text
                         };

MKNetworkOperation* operation = [theEngine operationWithPath:@"login.php" params:params httpMethod:@"POST"];

[operation addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {

    NSInteger responseCode = completedOperation.HTTPStatusCode;

    NSLog(@"Response Code: %ld", (long)responseCode);

}

                   errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
                       [self presentErrorWithMessage:error.localizedDescription];
                   }];

[theEngine enqueueOperation:operation];
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have used successfully is to create a mySQL based web service using PHP and then use AFNetworking to connect to it.

Here is a great tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

Comment: What does AFNetworking have the purpose of doing versus MKNetworkKit as shown below? Doesn't MKNetworkKit have AFNetworking as part of it in some capacity?